# how can i use dynamodb geo library for java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, gradle, amazon-dynamodb

i have to make a server for geo service with java spring framework.
i want to use dynamoDB's geo library to query and save geo data.
So i read github examples [geo library example git hub](https://github.com/amazon-archives/dynamodb-geo)

and aws docs.

but when i loaded library for it with gradle or maven project, i couldn't load any libraries...

Is that library has been deprecated??
code below is gradle project and maven project respectively.

thank you.

```
runtimeOnly group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-bom', version: '1.11.979', ext: 'pom'
runtimeOnly group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.11.979'
implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-core', version: '1.11.979'
implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-dynamodb', version: '1.11.979'
implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'dynamodb-geo', version: '2.1.0'

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>${aws-java-sdk.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.979</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws.geo</groupId>
        <artifactId>dynamodb-geo</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This API is 8 years old and is no longer supported.

Comment: https://github.com/amazon-archives/dynamodb-geo indicates exactly that.

Comment: Is there any libraries for java that can be used instead of that??